# EC2 connection timeout using putty

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

please bear with me. I have created lot of EC2 instances in aws and connected it using putty in windows. I know the whole process. But from yesterday, when i created a new EC2 instance, created a new security group with SSH open to 0.0.0.0/0 cidr, created a new key pair, generated private key using putty gen and used it to open in putty. I get network timeout connection. I spent whole day to figure out the issue with no idea on why it is not connecting. By the way i am using public IP specified in aws console for the Ec2.

Comment: I generally use amazon.pem file to connect ...  Its more cleaner

Comment: it does not work with both pem and ppk files

Comment: Can you connect to another instance in the _same subnet_?

Answer (score 2):

Just a hint: Please use http://ping.eu/port-chk/ to do a port check on port 22 with Public IP address of your EC2 server.
If it says open then something is wrong on your client side. Other wise If 22 shown as closed try if you can Ping the Instance, If you can Ping but 22 shown as Close then SSH service is down. But if you can not Ping as well you need to troubleshoot back in your SG, VPC NACL and Routing Tables to your VPC's Internet Gateway.

Answer (score 0):

Check whether your EC2 instance was launched in Public subnet or not. See if your public subnet has access to internet gateway route in the route table in VPC dashboad.